# Значение оператора php

Tags: php

Какой смысл оператора "|=" ? Установка значения?

Пример:

```
$b404 |= (intval($arVariables["SECTION_ID"])."" !== $arVariables["SECTION_ID"]);
```

Что обозначает вышеприведенный кусок кода?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пойдем по порядку.

`$b404 |= (intval($arVariables["SECTION_ID"])."" !== $arVariables["SECTION_ID"]);`

можно записать по-другому:

`$b404 = $b404 | (intval($arVariables["SECTION_ID"])."" !== $arVariables["SECTION_ID"]);`

Возможно вы знаете откуда это пошло, но на всякий случай напомню, что так частенько любят поступать, когда у вас, к примеру в переменной есть уже значение и вы хотите, например прибавить к этому значению еще какое-либо. Чтобы не писать в той же строчке эту же переменную, есть короткий синтаксис.

Наглядно:

```
$points = 600;
$add = 300;

$points += $add;
echo $points // выведет 900
```

Если не сокращать, то по факту получается вот так:

```
$points = 600;
$add = 300;

$points = $points + $add;
echo $points // выведет 900
```

Аналогично и с оператором `|`.

`|` - один из [побитовых операторов](https://secure.php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.bitwise.php). Конкретно он означает побитовое или.

`$a | $b` - Устанавливаются те биты, которые установлены в `$a` или в `$b`.

Например, в двоичной системе число 12 будет выглядеть как `1100`, а 2 — как `0010`, так что выражение `12|2` вернет нам число 14 (`1110` в двоичной записи)

---

Это удобно например для установления каких-либо прав для юзера, подробнее можно увидеть это применение [здесь](https://secure.php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.bitwise.php#108679)

Хотя в вашем случае возможно просто в последствие проверяется

`if ($b404){ // do smth }` , где `$b404` - true или false.

Так как в выражении `(intval($arVariables["SECTION_ID"])."" !== $arVariables["SECTION_ID"])` оператор `!==` в правой части дает понять, что результатом операции ожидается  получить булев тип то в целом операция сводится к одному из четырех вариантов:

```
0000 | 0001
или
0000 | 0000
или
0001 | 0001
или
0001 | 0000
```

Итог этой операции: `true` или `false`

Comment: Для полноценного ответа вам не хватает разбора конструкции `intval($val)."" !== $val` ;)

Comment: @DmitriySimushev но вопрос же об операторе)) может я у вас украду кусок кода? :-D

Comment: только с указанием авторства (код на ru.SO под лицензией MIT) ;)

Answer (score 1):

Оператор `|=` в PHP это сокращение для связки

```
$b404 = $b404 | $value;
```

В свою очередь, оператор `|` это оператор [побитового ИЛИ](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8#.D0.9F.D0.BE.D0.B1.D0.B8.D1.82.D0.BE.D0.B2.D0.BE.D0.B5_.D0.98.D0.9B.D0.98_.28OR.29). Этот оператор возвращает последовательность битов, в которой бит имеет значение `1` если на соответствующей позиции хотя бы одного из операндов есть `1` и `0` в противном случае.

К примеру:

```
(0b10101 | 0b11011) === 0b11111;
```

---

Теперь разберем ваш конкретный случай. Конструкция

```
intval($val)."" !== $val
```

проверяет, что переменная `$val` не является строкой содержащей *только* целое число. На выходе получается логическое значение `true` или `false`. При использовании в конструкции `|=` это значение приводится к целочисленному `1` или `0`.

Результат конструкции:

```
$b404 |= (intval($val)."" !== $val);
```

зависит от изначального значения переменной `$b404`. Однако, после выполнения кода, последний бит этой переменной будет установлен в `1` если `$val` не является строкой, содержащей *только* целое число и не будет изменен в противном случае.

По сути, вся конструкция используется для валидации входного параметра `$arVariables["SECTION_ID"]`, чтобы убедиться, что этот параметр содержит только число.

Comment: И вам спасибо за помощь:)